# Unit testing a complex renderer class (Best Practices)

Tags: java, testing, rendering, bufferedimage

I'm trying to test a class which purpose is taking a specification of what to do with a BufferedImage array and proccess it.

I'm concerned about how to aproach this task, it makes no sense to me just duplicate the function code on the test in order to generate a "expected bufferedImage array" and check if the generated BufferedImages are equals to the returned by the class methods.

I've read some slightly similar questions here, but the answers was "charge expected images from file and check with returned ones by class methods" but that sounds real hard to maintain if the proccess changes, new methods are added to the renderer class, it's hard or imposible pregenerate a resulting image or simply the class is refactorized and functions are splitted.

My actual question might be: Is there a little more elegant, "better to maintain" way to do that. I haven't so much experience with unit testing so i'm not sure about how to do this.

**EDIT:** sorry for the long code, i simplified and translated it. Excuse me if i did a bad translation. english it's not my main language.

```
public class Renderer extends SwingWorker<BufferedImage[], Integer>
{
  private Device device;
  private Main main;
  private Controller controller;
  public static final int FPS = 25;



  public Renderer(Device device, Main main, Controller controller)
  {
    this.device = device;
    this.main = main;
    this.controller = controller;
  }

  @Override
  protected BufferedImage[] doInBackground() throws Exception
  {

    // rendering image array
    BufferedImage[] output = renderize(main.getActualEscene());
    LOG.log.log(Level.INFO, "Rendering");
    // getting how many times should repeat 
    String stringRepeat =
        main.getActualEscene().getProperties().get(TextProperties.REPEAT.toString());
    int repeat = (stringRepeat == null) ? 1 : Integer.parseInt(stringRepeat);
    // getting text speed
    String stringFps =
        main.getActualEscene().getProperties().get(TextProperties.TEXT_SPEED.toString());
    int fps = (stringFps == null) ? FPS : Integer.parseInt(stringFps);
    if (!this.isCancelled()) // if this task is not cancelled
    {
      // we create a pre-viewer
      controller.setPreviewer(
          new Previewer(controller, repeat, fps, main.getActualEscene()));
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
      {// sincronizing this code with AWT thread

        @Override
        public void run()
        { // if it's not cancelled
          if (controller.getPreviewer() != null
              && !controller.getPreviewer().isCancelled())
          {
            controller.getPreviewer().execute(); //execute the task
          }

        }

      });
    }


    return output;
  }

  /**
   * Renders a scene and transforms it in a image array, then save it to the scene
   * 
   * @param scene -> scene 
   * @return an array with the scene frames
   */
  public BufferedImage[] renderize(Scene scene)
  {
    BufferedImage[] output = null; // end result
    BufferedImage[] base = new BufferedImage[1]; // base image
    BufferedImage[] animationImages = null; // animation layer
    BufferedImage[] textLayer = null; // text layer
    BufferedImage[] overLayer = null; // overlayer


    // omitted long process to retrieve image properties

    // once the text properties are retrieved if it's not null it will be rendered
    if (text != null)
    {
      String backgroundColorString =
          scene.getProperties().get(TextProperties.BACKGROUND_COLOR.toString());
      int backGroundcolorInt = Integer.parseInt(backgroundColorString);
      if (animationImages != null) // if there is an animation layer we create a same size text layer
      {
        textLayer = new BufferedImage[animationImages.length];
      } else 
      {
        textLayer = new BufferedImage[1];
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < textLayer.length; i++)
      {
        textLayer[i] = new BufferedImage(device.getWidth(), device.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      }
      String font = scene.getProperties().get(TextProperties.FONT.toString());
      int lettersHeigth = device.getHeight() / 3;
      int colorNumber =
          Integer.parseInt(scene.getProperties().get(TextProperties.TEXT_COLOR.toString()));
      textLayer = addTextToAImage(text, font, lettersHeigth, new Color(colorNumber),
          new Color(backGroundcolorInt), textLayer);
    }
    // has it overlayer?

    if (scene.getProperties().containsKey(AnimationProperties.OVER.toString())) // if it has over
    {
      String over = scene.getProperties().get(AnimationProperties.OVER.toString());
      overLayer =
          this.readingImagesFromAnimation(OverLibrary.getInstance().getOverByName(over));
    }

    // mixing layers
    output = base; // adding base base
    if (animationImages != null) // if there is animation layer we add it
    {
      output = mixingTwoImages(output, animationImages);
    }
    if (textLayer != null) // if there is text layer
    {
      output = mixingTwoImages(output, textLayer);
    }
    if (overLayer != null) //if there is overlayer
    {
      output = mixingTwoImages(output, overLayer);
    }
    // delimiting image operative zone.
    output = delimite(output, device);
    main.getActualEscene().setPreview(new Preview(output));
    LOG.log.log(Level.INFO, "Rendering scene finished: " + scene.getNombre());
    return output;

  }

  /**
   * Apply the device mask to an image. Delimiting the scene operative zone.
   * 
   * @param input -> BufferedImage array which need to be delimited
   * @param device -> device which it mask need to be applied
   * @return An BufferedImage array with a delimited image for the device.
   */
  private BufferedImage[] delimite(BufferedImage[] input, Device device)
  {
    BufferedImage[] output = new BufferedImage[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) // copy all original frames
    {
      output[i] = new BufferedImage(device.getWidth(), device.getHeight(),
          BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D graphics = output[i].createGraphics();
      graphics.drawImage(input[i], 0, 0, null);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) // for each frame
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < output[i].getHeight(); j++) // for each row
      {
        for (int k = 0; k < output[i].getWidth(); k++) // for each column
        {
          if (!device.estaEnZonaOperativa(j, k)) // if the coordinate is not in the operative zone
          {
            int pixel = 0x00000000; // we create a transparent pixel
            output[i].setRGB(j, k, pixel); // set the original pixel with this new one
          }

        }
      }
    }
    return output;
  }

  /**
   * method that reads an animation images and returns it into an array
   * 
   * @param animation -> animación de la que obtendremos sus image
   * @return array de BufferedImage con los frames de la animación ordenados por orden de lectura
   *         ascendente.
   */
  private BufferedImage[] readingImagesFromAnimation(Animation animation)
  {
    BufferedImage[] output = new BufferedImage[animation.getData().length];
    for (int i = 0; i < animation.getData().length; i++) // for each frame
    {
      try
      {
        File ruta = animation.getData()[i]; // getting its path
        output[i] = ImageIO.read(ruta); // reading from the path and save it into output
      } catch (IOException e)
      {
        LOG.log.log(Level.SEVERE, "error reading animation file: " + animation.getData()[i],
            e);
      }
    }
    return output;
  }

  /**
   * create a text layer an add it to the image parameter center
   * 
   * @param text -> text to include
   * @param font -> font of the text
   * @param size -> size
   * @param color -> text color
   * @param image -> image you want to add text
   * @return a text layer that need to be mixed with original one.
   */
  private BufferedImage[] addTextToAImage(String text, String font, int size, Color color,
      Color backgroundColor, BufferedImage[] image)
  {
    // we set the size of the output as the same of the original image
    BufferedImage[] output = new BufferedImage[image.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) // for each frame
    {
      output[i] = new BufferedImage(image[i].getWidth(), image[i].getHeight(),
          BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); // we create a single new image
      Graphics2D graphics = output[i].createGraphics(); // get its graphics
      // calculate for metrics
      Font font = new Font(font, Font.PLAIN, size); // create a font
      graphics.setFont(font); // setting it into the graphics
      FontMetrics fontMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics(font); // generating metric object

      // calculate the text coordinates
      int x = (image[i].getWidth() - fontMetrics.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
      int y = ((image[i].getHeight() - fontMetrics.getAscent() - fontMetrics.getDescent()) / 2)
          + fontMetrics.getAscent();
      int width = fontMetrics.stringWidth(text); // usefull metric to set a brackground
      int height = fontMetrics.getAscent() + fontMetrics.getDescent(); 

      // setting a background
      graphics.setColor(backgroundColor);
      graphics.fill(new Rectangle(x, y - fontMetrics.getAscent(), width, height));

      // drawing text
      graphics.setColor(color); // setting a color for text
      graphics.drawString(text, x, y); 
    }
    return output;
  }

  /**
   * method to join two bufferedImage arrays and mix them. The shortest array will be played on loop
   * 
   * WARNIN: the images needs to has the same resolution
   * 
   * @param image -> image mixed as background
   * @param image2 -> image mixed as foreground
   * @return a mixed image array.
   */
  private BufferedImage[] mixingTwoImages(BufferedImage[] image, BufferedImage[] image2)
  {
    // checking no empty images.
    if (image.length == 0 || image2.length == 0) 
    {
      RuntimeException exception =
          new RuntimeException("empty images");
      LOG.log.log(Level.SEVERE, exception.getMessage(), exception);
      throw exception;
    }
    int width = Math.max(image[0].getWidth(), image2[0].getWidth());
    int height = Math.max(image[0].getHeight(), image2[0].getHeight());
    // creating a sequence of the longest size of them
    BufferedImage[] output = new BufferedImage[Math.max(image.length, image2.length)];
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) // for each frame
    {
      // we create a frame
      output[i] = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics g = output[i].getGraphics();
      // mixing the frame 
      if (image.length > image2.length) // if the first array is longer
      {
        g.drawImage(image[i], 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(image2[i % image2.length], 0, 0, null);
      } else if (image.length < image2.length) // if the second array is longer
      {
        g.drawImage(image[i % image.length], 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(image2[i], 0, 0, null);
      } else // bot of the same size
      {
        g.drawImage(image[i], 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(image2[i], 0, 0, null);
      }
    }
    return output;
  }
```

Comment: Could you include your class code here?

Comment: Is it possible to process a 1x1 pixel big image? You could assume by the logic, if the resulting pixel is black or white or any other color and then simply check, if the pixel is that expected color.

Comment: @MoonMoo class code is quite long i'm simplifiying and i will post it.

Comment: @Korashen i'm not sure i'm getting you... Do you mean process a resulting imagen to a 1x1 pixel result and then compare it?

Comment: @MoonMoo code added

Comment: @Eos Took a glance at your code, can not read it all in detail right now. You fetch the current scene from your `main` object. For your test, provide the current scene to be a 1 pixel big image, or maybe even 5 pixel or similar to this. Then process the image in your renderer. Then analyses the resulting image pixel by pixel. Doing this with 1 to 10 pixels is no big effort.

Comment: I got you now @Korashen, thank you for the idea, but i'm not sure we can apply this because the rendered image is a compose of another images privided by an animation, text, overlayer... (in this case 32x32 pixels). I could create all the resources with a 2x2 pixel map, but my question goes a little bit far. How do you test a code that proccess an image without duplicating code and decoupling the test from the resources? i would like to implement a test that doesn't need to be changed if the animation library changes if it's possible.